# Fix z-index with overlapping dropdowns

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having a problem in a project I'm working on with z-index.

I have several components which all have a dropdown. The problem I have is that the dropdown from the first components goes under the dropdown button of the second and this makes the content partially hidden.

I basically need the first dropdown to have the highest z-index. But as I'm styling them all the same, they all have the same z-index.

I'd like to solve this without JavaScript where I have to dynamically change the z-index or the solution with flexbox that's attached to the code snippet.

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.app-item-dropdown');

dropdowns.forEach((item) => {
  item.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.parentNode.classList.toggle('expanded')
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --z1: 1;
  --z2: 2;
  --z3: 3;
  --z4: 4;
  --z5: 5;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 24px;
}

.solution {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.app-item {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin: 24px;
}

.app-item-dropdown {
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 272px;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  background: white;
  z-index: var(--z2);
}

.app-item-dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  position:relative;
  z-index: var(--z4);
}

.app-item-dropdown ul li {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

.app-item-dropdown.expanded ul{
  display: block;
}

.lightblue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.lightsalmon {
  background: lightsalmon; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="container problem">
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightblue">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>3</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightsalmon">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<hr>
<h1>Solution</h1>
<h2>With <code>flex-direction: column-reverse</code> </h2>


<div id="wrapper2" class="container solution">
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightblue">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>3</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightsalmon">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, in theory it could be an infinite amount of dropdowns. In the app i've seen people have hundreds of these components.

Comment: You want to do it without the existing JavaScript that you have? Or without additional JavaScript?

Comment: It uses javascript for the dropdown logic, but I prefer to solve the z-index issue without. Only if possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the z-index of the class you're adding on click higher than the z-index of the existing elements.

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.app-item-dropdown');

dropdowns.forEach((item) => {
  item.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.parentNode.classList.toggle('expanded')
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --z1: 1;
  --z2: 2;
  --z3: 3;
  --z4: 4;
  --z5: 5;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 24px;
}

.solution {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.app-item {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin: 24px;
}

.app-item-dropdown {
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 272px;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  background: white;
  z-index: var(--z2);
}

.app-item-dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  position:relative;
  z-index: var(--z4);
}

.app-item-dropdown ul li {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

.app-item-dropdown.expanded ul{
  display: block;
}

.lightblue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.lightsalmon {
  background: lightsalmon; 
}

.expanded {
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="container problem">
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightblue">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>3</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightsalmon">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<hr>
<h1>Solution</h1>
<h2>With <code>flex-direction: column-reverse</code> </h2>


<div id="wrapper2" class="container solution">
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightblue">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="app-item">
    <h2>3</h2>
    <div class="app-item-dropdown lightsalmon">
      <button>click</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hellohello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hehellohellollo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>helhellolo</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```